# Why use hierarchical taxonomies instead of many custom taxonomies?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Or vice versa. What reasons are there for choose one over the other?

[image: hierarchical taxonomies]

vs

[image: multiple custom taxonomies]

I realize the examples I gave may not be the best dummy data, but pretend, in this instance, that I have a blog for animal pictures. A single post could have both dogs and cats.

Performance? Issues trying to use Prev and Next links? URL structure? Or would both options be practically the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you needed an archive page that listed all dogs, then the hierarchical approach would be much efficient. You could visit `/category/dogs', and Bob's your uncle.

If you used separate categories for every breed of dog, then that dogs archive would require a custom query to select everything from every individual breed in the `dogs` taxonomy.